# How to use numerical solution in differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I have numerical solution for variable $p$ (as series of numbers), which I got through ode45 method in MAtlab. I need to calculate $u$, where

$$u=\dfrac{r^2-1}{16}\dfrac{dp}{dz}$$

May I use my numerical solution for $p$ and calculate $\dfrac{dp}{dz}$ in second equation? Is it possible in matlab and on which way?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, though you'll probably need to calculate a numerical derivative, more like $\Delta p/\Delta z$. If you searched for "numerical derivative", I imagine you could find something that would work.

Comment: So essentially, you want to calculate the numerical value of $\frac{dp}{dz}$ given numerical values of $p(z)$. There are many ways of doing this, depending on the accuracy that you want. The simplest one is of course
$$
\frac{dp}{dz}\left( z_i +\frac{1}{2}\Delta z \right) = \frac{p(z_i+\Delta z) - p(z_i)}{\Delta z}
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient